# angular state refresh-page does not work in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, page-refresh

I have angular app with routing:  `<base href="/application/">`

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'js/templates/main.html'
            })
            .state('main.admin', {
                url: '^/admin',
                templateUrl: 'js/templates/admin-page.html',
                controller: 'AdminController'
            })...
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

When I use links like

```
<li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active">
                <a href class="custom-tab-label" ui-sref="main.admin"Admin</a>
            </li>
```

all works fine. link is http://localhost:8080/application/admin

But when I try to refresh this page - there is 404 error.

Where is the problem?

Comment: This has to be set in backend

Comment: Yes, but I need to use angular routing for requests like in navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to instruct your server-side to use angular routing... [here is a link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) on how to do it...

e.g. in IIS

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```